# C++ (gcc/g++) Two huge arrays of strings take extremely long to compile

Tags: c++, arrays, string, static, constants

For a program written in C++, I need two huge arrays of strings that contain data.

They are defined in a header file as follows:

```
#include <string>
static const string strdataA[30000]={"this is the first line of the data",
    "the second line of data",
    "other stuff in the third line",
```

down to

```
    "last line."};
//second array strings
static const string strdataB[60000]={"this is the first line of the data",
    "the second line of data",
    "other stuff in the third line",
```

down to

```
    "last line."};
```

But when I compile this with g++, it takes so long that I have not seen it complete. It also uses about two GB of virtual memory. So I commented out strdataB[], and then the program did compile, but still after a long while. The executable was only about 8 Mb and worked fine.

What can I do in order to speed up the compiling process? I don't mind if I have to change the code, but I don't want to use an external file to load from. I would like an array because it works extremely well for me inside the program.

I read on the net somewhere that "static const" should do the trick, but I learned by experience that it doesn't.

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: How many lines are you talking about? Are there really 30,000 and 60,000 strings in your source?

Comment: I assume they are in a source file not a header file.

Comment: You realise that the loader has to do basically the same as you would do if you loaded the strings from an external file?

Comment: If they are constant texts, compile it once and be done. If they change often, put them in a database.

Comment: Yes, there are 30,000 and 60,000 strings, which is just about 9Mb of data, which isn't that much. They are in a header file. I don't want them in external files, because I don't want all kinds of extra files, I just want one single executable. A string array is easy from a programming point of view.

Comment: I tried this with 30,000 strings and g++ took about 1.2 GB of memory. Adding memory to avoid swapping should help for compilation speed.

Comment: Time comparison between `std::string` array and `char*` array is 5 minutes vs 2 seconds. The object size goes down from about 5 MB to just 1 MB.

Comment: Also, move the literals to a single translation unit, outside of the headers. Provide just an `extern` declaration in the header, and that will reduce the cost to a single translation unit (rather than all users of the header)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not use `std::string` for that. Use instead plain old `const char*`:

```
const char * const strdataA[30000] = {
    "one",
    "two",
    //...
};
```

The `static` keyword shouldn't make much of a difference here.

This way, the strings themselves will be stored in the read-only data section as simple literals, and the array itself will be simply an array of pointers. Also, you avoid running the strings constructors/destructors at runtime.

Comment: This did the trick indeed, it now compiles in a blink of the eye. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe these are known issues in GCC. You do not say what version of GCC you are using, maybe you should try with the newest stable release of GCC, to see if it does or does not improve things.

You probably should not keep all of your string in source code any. You should probably load them from external file at startup or such.

Comment: Agreed, by keeping the strings external and loading at startup the program is much easier to modify. This requires code modification to fix typos in a string.

Comment: @Chris.Stover In general, I agree with you both. However, if for example you are storing the schema of your configuration file in your source code, then I would think that was a good idea for security reasons.

Comment: gcc --version gives "gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-11lucid3) 4.7.2", the latest I could get. External data files/database could be a solution, but I just want a single executable, not several different files.

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do in order to speed up the compiling process?

`const char* strdataA ...` should speed up the compilation process. Because in your current version g++ must create huge list of constructor calls for every single string.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution indeed.